# How to make clickable images that acts like input file

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two input files and two images not I am trying to create a clickable image that will act like an input file and store the file name in it using Vue 3 but I keep on getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'click'`) error when I click on the image

Here is my code

```
 <template>
 <input class="form-control" type="file" @change="handleFileUpload($event, 'image1')"ref="fileInputRefs[0]" style="display: none;">
 <img src="front.png" class="images" @click="handleImageClick(0)">

 <input class="form-control" type="file" @change="handleFileUpload($event, 'image1')"ref="fileInputRefs[1]" style="display: none;">
 <img src="back.png" class="images" @click="handleImageClick(1)">


<script setup>
  const fileInputRefs = [
             ref(null),
             ref(null)
    ] 

 const handleImageClick = (index) => {
   fileInputRefs[index].value.click()
 }

const handleFileUpload = (event, id) => {
const fileList = event.target.files
const reader = new FileReader()
reader.readAsDataURL(fileList[0])
 reader.onload = () => {
  if (id === 'image1') {
     file1.value = {
      file: fileList[0],
     dataUrl: reader.result
   }
  } else if (id === 'image2') {
  file2.value = {
    file: fileList[0],
    dataUrl: reader.result
    }
  }
 }
}



</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to bind ref (:ref):

```js
const { ref } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const fileInputRefs = ref([])
    const handleImageClick = (index) => {
      fileInputRefs.value[index].click()
    }
    const handleFileUpload = (event, id) => {
      const fileList = event.target.files
      const reader = new FileReader()
      reader.readAsDataURL(fileList[0])
      reader.onload = () => {
        if (id === 'image1') {
          fileInputRefs.value = {
            file: fileList[0],
            dataUrl: reader.result
          }
        } else if (id === 'image2') {
          fileInputRefs.value[1] = {
            file: fileList[0],
            dataUrl: reader.result
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return {
      handleImageClick, handleFileUpload, fileInputRefs
    };
  },
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <input class="form-control" type="file" @change="handleFileUpload($event, 'image1')" 
     :ref="el => { fileInputRefs[0] = el }" style="display: none;">
  <img src="front.png" class="images" @click="handleImageClick(0)">

  <input class="form-control" type="file" @change="handleFileUpload($event, 'image2')" 
    :ref="el => { fileInputRefs[1] = el }" style="display: none;">
  <img src="back.png" class="images" @click="handleImageClick(1)">
</div>
```